# Blank Locked Samsung S5

Tags: lock-screens, broken-screen

I have been searching internet for hours.  Ran over my phone so LCD not working.
Does not appear I had debug activated on this phone.   Phone comes up locked and I can't unlock it.    Any suggestions.  Really need help as is a work phone. 
I can connect ph to computer how do I bypass this so I can backup all my contracts and get my photos.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! As similar things are reported here quite frequently, we've set up some basic first-aid and useful links in our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info). Please have a look there and report back if something was solving your issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a software for Windows that emulates a second screen of an Android phone. Used it for a similar situation where I had a broken LCD screen  and USB debugging mode ON! I don't know if it will work for newer Android version. Just give it a try.

Download **Droid@Screen** from the [official page](http://droid-at-screen.org/).

Grab the application JAR file (droidAtScreen-xxx.jar) and double-click it.

Plug-in your Android device using the USB cable and a device frame will shortly pop-up.

*Prerequisites*:

- Java installed
- Android SDK, installed and configured.
- Environment variable ANDROID_HOME (or ANDROID_SDK_HOME) pointing the the Android SDK installation directory
- USB drivers for the  Android device installed

Comment: You said it was on! Or I didn't get the line:  `I had debug activated on this phone`